# Regex to match start and end line

Tags: regex

I am trying to compose a regex (for sublime text search) to match an exact start line, all the lines in between, and finally the exact end line.

So an example would be..

```
// START HERE
line 1
line 2
// STOP HERE
```

I have composed the following regex, but it has a limitation.

```
// START HERE\n(.*\n)+.*// STOP HERE
```

The problem is that it will group multiple occurrences of this pattern as one match...

```
// START HERE
line 1
line 2
// STOP HERE

// START HERE
line 1
line 2
// STOP HERE
```

In this case it will match the first // START HERE all the way to the second //STOP HERE.

How could I modify this to stop at the first // STOP HERE?

Comment: The easiest: `(?sm)^// START HERE\n(.*?)^// STOP HERE$`

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: That works if your linebreaks are `\n`. If not, replace `\n` with `\R`: `(?sm)^// START HERE\R(.*?)^// STOP HERE$`. Or just use `(?s)// START HERE(.*?)// STOP HERE`

Comment: the regex works if I remove the ^ characters, and breaks if I add them back in.

Comment: Anyway, the original question solves the issue of maching up to the first `//STOP HERE` (the lazy dot matching with a dotall modifier).